# Save each line to a string from a text document

Tags: c#

I'm trying to seperate each line from a text document and then save them to seperate strings. This is my text document:

```
CurrentVersion: 1.0.0.0
Update information: New GUI, Fixed login system.
```

I have 2 strings declared in my program.

```
string CurrentVersion = String.Empty;
string UpdateInfo = String.Empty;
```

I want the string CurrentVersion to hold the first line. So:

```
CurrentVersion = CurrentVersion: 1.0.0.0
```

And I want UpdateInfo to hold the second line. So:

```
UpdateInfo = Update information: New GUI, Fixed login system.
```

I've tried this code:

```
foreach(var myString in TextDocument.Text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
interpret(myString);
```

And when I call

```
MessageBox.Show(myString);
```

I get 2 MessageBoxes. The first MessageBox displays:

```
CurrentVersion: 1.0.0.0
```

And the second MessageBox displays

```
Update information: New GUI, Fixed login system.
```

But I want CurrentVersion and UpdateInfo to equal the lines. I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: "_But I want CurrentVersion and UpdateInfo to equal the lines._" What does this mean?

Comment: How can I make CurrentVersion equal the first line of the text document and UpdateInfo equal the second line of the document ?

Comment: You have to assign it. Inside your `foreach` you need to determine which line is which, then assign it. For example, you could make a counter and *assume* the 1st line is always the CurrentVersion line, `int counter = 0; foreach (var myString in text) {counter++; if (counter == 1) { CurrentVersion = myString; } }`; or you can do pattern matching: `foreach (var myString in text) { if (myString.Contains("CurrentVersion")) { CurrentVersion = myString; } }`.

Comment: @Rakitic Yeah, exactly like that. And UpdateInfo = Update information: New GUI, Fixed login system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string[] lines = TextDocument.Text.Split(new string[] 
    { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

string CurrentVersion = lines[0];
string UpdateInfo = lines[1];
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed. I tried similar methods but I always got an "Illegal character" error. But this works perfectly. Merci.